# Use of #include <iostream.h>

Tags: c++

I am working on an older project that still has the deprecated "#include iostream.h" inclusions. I understand that iostream.h is deprecated and should not be used, but some of the systems that this code has to run/compile on are old solaris machines running CC and do not have iostream available. My question is: how can I make my more modern g++ compiler accept the iostream.h inclusions.

EDIT: The compilier cannot find the iostream.h file so I am assuming that none of the .h versions of the library are available to g++.

Comment: is the -std=c++98 flag an option?

Comment: @Andy does that work? `iostream.h` was never in the C++98 standard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: not sure, I am not familiar with these old headers, i just thought the older standard might have supported them and provided a hint. it might well be wrong

Comment: @AndyProwl: Certainly doesn't work for me (g++ 4.7.2)

Comment: @NPE: ok, thank you for clarifying and sorry about the wrong hint

Comment: `iostream.h` is **not deprecated**. it has never been standard, so it's impossible to deprecate. it's a pre-standard header.

Comment: Thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf, [many answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22iostream.h%22+%22deprecated%22+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=555729795&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX4r70vtOAAxWscmwGHWxqCyYQrQIoBHoECCwQBQ&biw=1350&bih=598&dpr=1) use the term "deprecated" to describe `iostream.h`. Just to clarify, when [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) says: `"Notes: xxx.h headers are deprecated in C++98 and undeprecated in C++23. These headers are discouraged for pure C++ code, but not subject to future removal."` - it is talking about the headers in Annex D, yes?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf...whereas `iostream.h` was never part of Annex D, and so cannot be said to be "deprecated".

Comment: @user51462 Yes, "iostream.h" is not un-deprecated because it just isn't in the standard and never has been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a step back and write another intermediate header you use everywhere instead that does something like:

```
#if defined(sun) || defined(__sun)
# if defined(__SVR4) || defined(__svr4__)
/* Solaris */
#include <iostream>
# else
/* SunOS */
#include "iostream.h"
# endif
#else
/* Sane, modern system */
#include <iostream>
#endif
```

Comment: That was my thought as well, IM just not sure how to handle the namespace issue since the old SunOS doesnt understand namespaces. Modify that intermediate to include a "using namespace std" on places where iostream is defined?

Comment: -1 this is an ungood answer, in that system-detection for C and C++ is just as **extraordinarily bad** as browser detection for web pages. unless you're in the business of doing platform adaption, like boost.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - I would suggest feature detection instead of system detection, but short of switching to autotools that's not really viable (and autotools on old solaris is a PITA still)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is probably to create a local header file called `iostream.h` which just includes `<iostream>` and imports the namespace `std`. Then, in order for the compiler to allow `#include <iostream.h>` you add the local path to your include file search path. For g++, this works:

```
g++ -I local_folder [other flags] …
```

Incidentally, your remark about

> … the deprecated "#include iostream.h"

isn’t quite correct: this isn’t deprecated because it has never been legal C++.

Comment: But doesn't '<iostream>' require a std namespace?

Comment: You probably want it to do `#include <iostream>\nusing namespace std;` to have some hope of the code compiling/working.

Comment: @Matt I wasn’t sure so I kept my answer intentionally vague. Just add the `using namespace std;` then.

Comment: +1 this is a good answer. but please add information about the OP's erroneous claims about deprecation. it would be bad for SO to serve as a means of propagating such misconceptions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well I actually think that your comment on the question is a much better place to admonish that but I’ve added it for what it’s worth.